# Vuejs bind custom event on nested component within for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using three single-file-components.

- `ParentVariation.vue`
- `VariationInfo.vue`
- `Childvariation.vue`

I'm emitting `MarkedFilled` event from child component `variation-info`, and catching that event on `ParentVariation`. Here's the content of `ParentVariation.vue` :

```
<template>
    <section class="parentVariation">
        <label :for="'key-'+row.id">Key</label>

        <select :name="'key-'+row.id" :id="'key-'+row.id" class="select2"></select>

        <label :for="'value-'+row.id">Value</label>
        <input :name="'value-'+row.id" :id="'value-'+row.id">

        <label :for="'quantity-'+row.id">quantity</label>
        <input :name="'quantity-'+row.id" :id="'quantity-'+row.id">

        <variation-info :filled="row.filled" @markedFilled="row.filled='true'" :key="row.id"></variation-info>

        <button @click="addChild" type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm btn-fw">
            <i class="mdi mdi-table-column-plus-after"></i>
            Add Child
        </button>

        <button @click="popChild" type="button" class="btn btn-link text-danger btn-sm btn-fw">
            <i class="mdi mdi-table-column-remove"></i>
            Drop Child
        </button>

        <br>

        <div v-if="row.child.length > 0">
            <child-variation v-for="child in row.child" :childIndex="child.id" :parentIndex="row.id" :key="child.id"></child-variation>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        props: [ 'row' ],

        methods: {

            addChild() {
                this.row.child.push({ id:this.row.child.length, filled:'' })
            },

            popChild() {
                this.row.child.pop()
            },

        }

    }
</script>
```

On the Main Vue-Instance. i have this:

```
data: function() {
   return {
       parents: [{ id:0, child: [], filled:'' }]
   }
},
```

And I've initialized `ParentVariation` like so:

```
<parent-variation v-for="parent in parents" :row="parent" :key="parent.id"></parent-variation>
```

i'm trying to achieve this functionality: When `MarkedFilled` event is called from child component (`variation-info`). Parent component (`parent-variation`) will catch that & update filled property for data parent on main vue instance.

But each time this event is called, only first parent element's filled property is changed. I want to change the property of the clicked element.

I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days now, Any help is appreciated. 
I just want to understand why only first element is called each time.

Comment: You should change `data` to function https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Comment: @ittus I'm so sorry about that. I've updated ```data```  to a function now.

Comment: If you are trying to change filled property of a specific object you should send that parent's id in the emit than call a function on @markedFilled and then change the filled property according to the id in that function.

Comment: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/passing-data-back-to-parent/1201/2 look for the answer by ktsn it explains how you can pass data on emit and call a function on that emit.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try emitting `markedFilled` event to parent component:

In `ParentVariation.vue`

```
<variation-info :filled="row.filled" @markedFilled="$emit('markedFilled')" :key="row.id">
</variation-info>
```

and in main

```
<parent-variation v-for="(parent, index) in parents" :row="parent" :key="parent.id" @markedFilled="changeFilled(index)">
</parent-variation>

export default {
  data: function() {
   return {
       parents: [{ id:0, child: [], filled:'' }]
   }
  },
  methods: {
    changeFilled(index) {
      this.parents[index].filled = true
      this.parents = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.parents))
    }
  }
}
```